# How to share Eclipse-project preferences among different team-members using Oomph

Tags: eclipse, oomph

I'm trying to share preferences with other developers in my Team using Oomph's Project Model. What I did so far:

1. Create a `Setup Project Model` using the template `Simple Project`
2. Import the current Preferences using the icon `Capture Preferences`

Now I have a .setup-File that contains (hopefully) my current preferences. But how do I share this file? I expect that there is some way to convince eclipse to read this file and to sync the preferences with it. I was hoping I could commit this file to SVN and eclipse would then read this file on every Startup...

Is something like this possible, and how is it done?

Comment: See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Oomph/article.html

Comment: Does this mean, that it is not possible to "connect" a Setup Project Model to an already installed Eclipse?

Comment: Which preferences are you talking about? Project-specific settings (e. g. compiler settings, formatting, etc.) are shared via the project subfolder `.settings` without Oomph. Oomph is useful if you want to automatically e. g. check out repositories or install required plug-ins.

Comment: Yes project-specific settings. I used .settings in the past, but in bigger workspaces with a lot projects this becomes hard to maintain, since you would have to set the same settings in several projects. As a little workaround I used to copy the contents of .settings from one project to another, but this also means, that I would have to do that several times when I want to change something.

Comment: You might have a look at [Workspace Mechanic](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/workspace-mechanic) for that.